# ElasticSearch Mapping and Default Values When Wrong Format

Tags: elasticsearch

I have a field in elastic search with `"type": "integer"`

If a string (or any NaN value is passed), I want to just have it default to some integer value (like 0).

Is there a way to do this in ES?

Answer (score 3):

There is a way you can do it.

1. First change coerce to false , so that even if string integer like "23" ( and not 23 ) , comes , it wont parse it.
   LINK - http://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/1.4/mapping-core-types.html
2. Next put null_value as 0
   LINK - http://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/1.4/mapping-core-types.html

Comment: Will this work with non integer fields too? For example if I am expecting a nested object for some field but nothing is sent?

Comment: Btw, this didn't seem to work. I have an integer field, and i sent in "blah" for the value and it stored it as "blah" rather than my null_value

Comment: It would be stored this way in _source. I am talking about reverse index. WHen you search for blah , it wont work , but then null value will work.